# Как запустить в vs code 2 окна сразу?

Tags: python, сокет, visual-studio-code

Работаю с библиотекой socket и требуется запустить 2 файла. как это сделать?

Answer (score 0):

Ты можешь открыть еще одну консоль и прописать:

Вот так :
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Нажать на плюсик около слова bash

Если Linux/Mac:

```
python3 название.py
```

Windows:

```
python название.py
```